# Identify BlackBerry phones

Tags: java, android, blackberry, identify

How can I identify a BlackBerry KeyOne or Key2 phone from within Java on Android? I'm thinking that I could check `Build.MANUFACTURER` or `Build.PRODUCT`, but I don't have one of these phones on hand to test at the moment.

I have an app that has a bug on these phones, so I need to check for the type of phone and use a different method when needed, but I don't want to mess with the way it works on other devices.

Comment: So what is your question ? You want others to test if `Build.MANUFACTURER` returns `Blackberry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following one ouputs for example

```
String brandName = android.os.build.BRAND // Will output BlackBerry
String deviceName = android.os.build.MODEL // Will output the specific device
```

Can't check it with BlackBerry but this should do the job